# Is tensorflow row- or column-vector centric?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, vector, linear-algebra

I'm new to tensorflow, keras and a bit confused about how tf treats its input and matrix multiplication and all that jazz.

You see, in Linear Algebra (LA) you can treat contravariant vectors as columns matices(math standard)

[image]

or as rows matrices

[image]

Somewhere I've heard that:

1. a tensor of shape (n,) e.g. [1,2,3,4,5] is not considered as a "vector" according to tf. Only tensors of shape (n,1) and (1,n) are considered vectors. But in many manuals people use those words without any system. Createing complete confusion in my head.
2. a tensor of shape (n,1) is considered as a column vector (according to tf)
3. but sending this column-vector **(n,1)** to some layer.call() as an *input* you can see that it is treated as a row-vector, because it's being multiplicated on the **right** by a  *self.w*, but for column-oriented LA it must have been multiplicated by the *self.w* the **left**.

```
def call(self, inputs):
    return tf.matmul(inputs, self.w) + self.b
```

So the questions are these:

1. What does it mean being x-oriented according to tf?
2. Is tensor flow column-vector or row-vector oriented?
3. What's up with non-vectors (n,1), and why those are not "vectors" according to TF?
4. What is expected as an input to a layer column or row vectors?
5. left-right matrix multiplication x*W+b in TF source code. Why it's x on the right and M on the left and not vice-versa? Why if layer expects a column-vector as an input its being multiplied by W on the right?

I see that I'm confused and can't clearly state the question. Please, be patient. Thanks.

Comment: `tf.matmul(a,b)` where `a` is sized `(n,1)` and `b` is sized `(1,n)` will yield you an `(n,n)` matrix, just like multiplying a column vector by a row vector will. As for what it means for `layer.call` i have no idea

Comment: I think tensorflow expects data to be in rows, and uses right multiplication by weight matrices as a way to represent linear functions in row vector space

Comment: @pqnet You say *tensorflow expects data to be in rows* you mean that ```layer.call(x)``` where X is a row vector with shape (1,n)?

Comment: yes, I think so. And the result will be a  row vector too. The weight matrix `w` should be a `n,m` matrix, and the bias a `m, 1` row vector

Comment: @pqnet But *bias* is of form **(m,)** and **not (m,1)** which confuses me much. And, as i heard somewhere (n,) are not row vectors and not even vectors according to tf.

Comment: what confuses me is that TF freely throws Linear algebra words around. I mean, why the hell this is allowed:
```b = tf.constant([1,2,3,4]);
z = tf.constant([[1,1,1,1],[2,2,2,2]]); print(z+b);
>>> tf.Tensor(
 [[2 3 4 5]
 [3 4 5 6]], shape=(2, 4), dtype=int32)``` This is nonsense!

Comment: It seems to me (m,) vectors behave like column vectors.

Answer (score 0):

It is because the elements of a rank 1 tensor are treated as a scalar.

For example

Example 1.

```
x = tf.constant(5)
y = tf.constant([1,2,3])
```

x*y will produce [5,10,15]

Example 2.

```
x = tf.constant([1,2,3])
y = tf.constant([[1],[2],[3]])
```

x*y will produce [[1 2 3] [2 4 6] [3 6 9]].

It also uses broadcast, whenever the shapes are incompatible. https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html